# Array Pointer Program to Flip Bits and Add One

Tags: c, malloc, bit

I am trying to write a program that will take an arbitrary number and flip the bits and add one, and I have written the code, but I keep getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) error. Could someone look at my code and see why that error is occurring. I have attached my code below and the input and output I would like to receive.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "malloc.h" //Needed for malloc, realloc, and free

#define GROW_BY 2
#define MAX_BITS 32

int add_one(int in_array[], int num){
        for (int i = 0; in_array[i] != NULL; i++) {
                int add_one = in_array[num - i] + 1;
        }
        return add_one;
}

int main() {

        //Declaration and Initialization of Variables
        int* array = NULL;

        int bit = getchar();
        int count = 0;
        while (bit != '\n') {
                bit = bit - '0';
                *array = &bit;
                array = (int*)malloc((strlen(bit) + 1) * sizeof(int));
                if (array == NULL) {
                        printf("An error has occurred and the program will now $
                        return 1;
                }
                bit = getchar();
        }

        for (int j = count - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
                if (array[j] == '1') {
                        array = (int*)realloc(array, GROW_BY * sizeof(int));
                        if (array == NULL) {
                                printf("An error has occurred and the program w$
                        }
              }
                else if (array[j] == '0' ) {
                        array = (int*)realloc(array, GROW_BY * sizeof(int));
                        if (array == NULL) {
                                printf("An error has occurred and the program w$
                                return 1;
                        }
                }
        }

        add_one(array, bit);

        for (int j = count - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
                if (array[j] == '1' && add_one == 1) {
                        array[j] = '0';
                }
                else if (array[j] == '0' && add_one == 1) {
                        array[j] = '1';
                        int add_one = 0;
                }
                else {
                        array[j] = array[j];
                }
        }


        printf("%ls/n", array);

        free(array);

        return 0;
}

Input: 101011110
Output: 010100010
```

Comment: Did you try a debugger? What do you think *array = &bit; is supposed to do?

Comment: When you step through the code in the debugger, which line is causing the fault? What does reading that line carefully tell you?

Comment: the posted code fails to compile!.  Please post a [mcve] so we can help you

Comment: why are you calling strlen(bit), bit is an int value, which, according to your sample input, should either be 0 or 1. calling strlen(0) is essentially passing a null pointer to strlen.

Comment: There are many issues. Actually about every thing in this piece of code is wrong. IMO this code is unsalvageable. You should start reading your C text book from the beginning. At least compile with all warnings enabled and treat them as errors, but I'm not sure this will help much with your level of knowledge.